# How to match a string and ignore everything after it?

Tags: python, regex

So here is the deal, I want to match a number and a string that comes after it. Like a buying list, "10 bananas" or "15 apples". The problem is, the same regex has to match "10 banana" but can't match "10 banana milkshake".

Regexes I already tried:

```
r"\b[0-9]{1,5}.banana"
r"\b[0-9]{1,5}.banana\b"
r"\b[0-9]{1,5}.banana$"
```

Example:

```
8 banana 3 banana ice cream 2 banana milkshake 5 banana
```

From that string, I need to match only "8 banana" and "5 banana".

With the regexes I tried, it matches "X banana" as expected, but I want it to be exactly "X banana" (where X is a number that appears 1-5 times, as in the regex) and ignore if it has anything else after it, like "ice cream" or "milkshake" in this example. Also, the "$" sign doesn't match anything if I put it on the regex.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't clear. Given that input, what exactly do you want to match?

Comment: [Your second regex is next to ideal](https://regex101.com/r/8tO3pl/1).

Comment: @DanielRoseman I edited the original post so it is clearer, hopefully.
I need to match, for example, "10 banana" but not match "10 banana milkshakes".

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That's the problem, It matches the word "banana" exactly as I want, but I need to match only "X banana" and not "X banana milkshakes", for example.

Comment: But the string you've posted has "8 banana 3 banana ice cream..." Are you saying you want to match "8 banana" and "5 banana" only from that? In other words "one or more digits, the exact word 'banana', followed by another digit or the end of the string"?

Comment: Does this do the trick `re.findall('\d+\s\w+', s)`?

Comment: @ettanany thats absolutely nonsense. I think he likes exactly what Daniel Roseman is describing.

Comment: [`^[0-9]{1,5}.banana|[0-9]{1,5}.banana$`](https://regex101.com/r/8tO3pl/3)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew [It doesn't match if "x banana" is in the middle of the string](https://regex101.com/r/8tO3pl/4) and the file I'm working with is a complete mess.
Thank you tho.

Comment: No, it is not the file, but your requirements are a mess. Please clarify what you need in the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew refer to the link in my previous comment (which I just added "5 banana" in the middle of the string in the regex you've linked). It has to match "8 banana", "5 banana"(in the middle), "5 banana" (in the end). It can't match "X BANANA SOMETHING" only "X BANANA".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `re.findall` with lookahead regex below, it assert banana must be following by digit or end of string. `s?` after banana to match plural bananas as well

```
import re
s = '8 banana 3 banana ice cream 2 banana milkshake 5 banana'
match = re.findall(r'\b[0-9]{1,5}.bananas?(?=\s?\d+|$)', s)
# ['8 banana', '5 banana']
```